# MSVC build Boost but Cmake findBoost doesn't work?

Tags: boost, cmake

To reproduce my issue... I [download Boost](https://dl.bintray.com/boostorg/release/1.64.0/source/boost_1_64_0.zip), then I run `booststrap` and `b2 --build-dir=C:\Users\xxx\Downloads\my_boost_build_dir --prefix=C:\Users\xxx\Downloads\my_boost_install_dir --layout=system variant=release link=static install`. Everything seems so far so good. The provided prefix (install) dir is populated with [headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g22fd.png) and [libs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybch9.png).

But here's where things start going wrong. If I write the following cmake file...

```
find_package(Boost REQUIRED)

message("Boost_FOUND" ${Boost_FOUND})
message("Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS" ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
message("Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS" ${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS})
message("Boost_LIBRARIES" ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
message("Boost_CHRONO_FOUND" ${Boost_CHRONO_FOUND})
message("Boost_CHRONO_LIBRARY" ${Boost_CHRONO_LIBRARY})

add_executable(main main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE Boost::boost Boost::chrono)
```

...and I configure it with the path to the boost install dir `cmake .. -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=C:\Users\xxx\Downloads\my_boost_install_dir`, then I get the following output and error...

```
Boost_FOUND1
Boost_INCLUDE_DIRSC:/Users/xxx/Downloads/my_boost_install_dir/include
Boost_LIBRARY_DIRSC:/Users/xxx/Downloads/my_boost_install_dir/lib
Boost_LIBRARIES
Boost_CHRONO_FOUND
Boost_CHRONO_LIBRARY
-- Configuring done
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:14 (add_executable):
  Target "main" links to target "Boost::chrono" but the target was not found.
  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or an
  ALIAS target is missing?
```

Boost is found, the include and lib dirs are found, but the chrono library (and all other libraries) are not. Maybe I need to explicitly name my components? So I tried this cmake instead...

```
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS chrono)

message("Boost_FOUND" ${Boost_FOUND})
message("Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS" ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
message("Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS" ${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS})
message("Boost_LIBRARIES" ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
message("Boost_CHRONO_FOUND" ${Boost_CHRONO_FOUND})
message("Boost_CHRONO_LIBRARY" ${Boost_CHRONO_LIBRARY})

add_executable(main main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE Boost::boost Boost::chrono)
```

But this produces the following output and error.

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.9/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1877 (message):
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Boost version: 1.64.0

  Boost include path: C:/Users/xxx/Downloads/my_boost_install_dir/include

  Could not find the following Boost libraries:

          boost_chrono

  Some (but not all) of the required Boost libraries were found.  You may
  need to install these additional Boost libraries.  Alternatively, set
  BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT
  to the location of Boost.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package)

Boost_FOUND0
Boost_INCLUDE_DIRSC:/Users/xxx/Downloads/my_boost_install_dir/include
Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS
Boost_LIBRARIES
Boost_CHRONO_FOUND
Boost_CHRONO_LIBRARY
```

Like before, it found boost and the headers, but for some reason it can't find the libraries.

Comment: If you need `chrono` component of the Boost, specify it in `find_package` call: `find_package(Boost REQUIRED chrono)`. Please, cleanup the question: As previous problem has been solved, just remove text corresponded to it (unless it is needed for describe the current problem). Stack Overflow maintains edit history for everyone who want to see previous content of the posts.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I cleaned up the question and tried listing the components but that didn't fix the issue. :-/

Comment: Hm, as you have `.lib` files, you may need to set `Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS` to ON before `find_package()`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Yes! Apparently that was the secret sauce.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use specific (non-header-only) Boost components, you have to specify them in `find_package`. In your case:

```
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS chrono REQUIRED)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindBoost.html

find_package(Boost) follow the hints below to find boost directories:

> BOOST_ROOT             - Preferred installation prefix  (or BOOSTROOT)
>
> BOOST_INCLUDEDIR       - Preferred include directory e.g.
>   /include
>
> BOOST_LIBRARYDIR       - Preferred library directory e.g. /lib
>
> Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS  - Set to ON to disable searching in locations
>   not
>                            specified by these hint variables. Default is OFF.
>
> Boost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS
>                          - List of Boost versions not known to this module
>                            (Boost install locations may contain the version)

If you don't know where is the default location to put your boost libraries and include files, you should set these variables before find_package.